# How to ask Visual Studio to compile by particular number of cores

Tags: visual-studio-2012, compilation, cl

We know in gnu-make, we can simply say that by something like -j2, -j4.

How to ask the Visual Studio to do similar things.

For example, my desktop has 8 cores, I need 4 cores to compile the code in C++ and the other 4 for me to do other things.

Answer (score 1):

You use the /MP switch and give it a number like "/MP4". See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385193.aspx)